# Cross crediting experience: Holder of ATC Instructor’s Qualification to NPPL(A) (SSEA)

Tags: pilot-certification, ppl, caa-uk-regulations, uk

I formerly held an ATC Instructor’s Qualification valid for the Vigilant Motor Glider through the RAF Volunteer Gliding Squadron System. I was a B1 Instructor until 2014 with 440 hours.

I would now like to obtain a UK civilian license for microlights, which I understand is still an NPPL(A) (SSEA), so I'm trying to understand what, if any, training dispensation I can use.

[CAP804 (April 2015)](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP804April2015REFONLY.pdf) section 2.1.6.2 states:

> The holder of the ATC Instructor’s Qualification valid for the Vigilant Motor Glider who
> wishes to obtain an NPPL(A) with SSEA Class Rating shall:

> a) produce log book evidence of having satisfactorily completed flying training on
> single-engine piston aeroplanes under the supervision of a FI(A), which must include:

> - i) not less than 1 hour dual instruction in stall/spin awareness and
>   avoidance;
> - ii) not less than 1 hour dual instrument appreciation;
> - iii) not less than 1 hour supervised solo flight; iv) not less than
>   4 hours navigation training or successful completion of the ‘Air
>   Cadet Vigilant Transit Qualification’ training syllabus, including
>   at least one solo  cross-country navigation exercise;

> b) pass the Part-FCL PPL(A) theoretical examinations;
> c) hold a valid NPPL Medical Declaration or Part-MED Class 1, 2 or LAPL medical
> certificate;
> d) pass the NPPL(A) NST and GST in an SSEA

However, CAP804 is now marked as "Reference Only" and I cannot find a document which has superceded it. At the advice of my instructor I have written to the [BMAA](https://www.bmaa.org/) for their advice, but received no response.

Can anyone tell me what the official requirements are today, please, or does it remain undefined since Brexit?

Answer (score 1):

The British Microlight Association kindly wrote back to me, I don't think I'm betraying any confidentiality in sharing their response here:

> On Wed, 14 Jun 2023 at 13:24, Pilot Licensing
> pilot.licensing@bmaa.org wrote: Hello Daniel,
>
> I’m afraid you are confused. You cannot fly a Microlight on a SSEA
> class rating, you would require a NPPL with Microlight (M) class
> rating.
>
> Have a read of section 4 of the attached and apply your
> qualifications. Cap 804 has not been superseded so remains the
> document we apply credit from.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Aaron Bliss BMAA Pilot Licensing, Instruction and Examinations

I've since checked and yes, to fly the Ikarus C42 I should aim for NPPL(M) not NPPL(SSEA).

The document he had attached was CAP 804 Part II (May 2012), referring to section four "CROSS-CREDITING LICENCES AND RATINGS TO NPPL (MICROLIGHT)" subsection 4.1.6:

> ATC Instructor’s Qualification to NPPL(A) (Microlight) The holder of
> the ATC Instructor’s qualification wishing to obtain an NPPL(A) with
> Microlight Class Rating shall: a) produce log book evidence of having
> satisfactorily completed not less than 15 hours  conversion training
> on Microlight aircraft under the supervision of a Microlight FI,
> which must include: i) not less than 6 hours supervised solo flight;
> ii) not less than 5 hours navigation training, to include not less
> than 3 hours solo  navigation including one qualifying cross-country
> flight as defined in the NPPL(A)  (Microlight) syllabus; b) pass the
> Microlight theoretical knowledge examinations; c) pass the Microlight
> Aeroplanes Type (Part 2) oral examination conducted by a  Microlight
> flight examiner. The examination shall include pilot maintenance
> requirements and conditions of the Permit to Fly; d) hold a valid NPPL
> Medical Declaration or Part-MED Class 1, 2 or LAPL medical
> certificate; e) pass the NPPL(A) GST on a Microlight